# Thread::tdlen: Objects of unequal length in {{a,b,e},{c,d,f}} {x,y,z} cannot be combined

Tags: list-manipulation

When I do the Times operation among list like this `{{a, b, e}, {c, d, f}}*{x, y, z}`, the error message is given as Thread::tdlen: Objects of unequal length in `{{a,b,e},{c,d,f}} {x,y,z}` cannot be combined. Actually, the desired result should be `{{a x, b y, e z}, {c x, d y, f z}}`. Are there any bugs?

Comment: `Inner[Times,{{a, b, e}, {c, d, f}},{x, y, z},List]` would be one way.

Comment: Another way `Times[{x, y, z}, #] & /@ {{a, b, e}, {c, d, f}}`.